# Perform action on UISearchBar when Keyboard is down and the x has been tapped

Tags: ios, selector, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have a `UITableView` with a `UISearchBar` on top and have a specific requirement that isn't working.

I have no Cancel button on my `UISearchBar (showsCancelButton = NO)` so I rely completely on the x within the `UISearchBar` to cancel the existing search. I rely on the Keyboard's "Search" button to dismiss the keyboard (though it's called Done in my case).

When a user searches in my app, I'm disabling a `navigation bar button` item because it gives a bad user experience, and only when the search has cancelled does the user get the navigation bar button item back. That's all working.

I have one particular scenario though that I cannot get around.

1) Tap on the Search Bar to enter Text

2) Click DONE on the Keyboard and the Keyboard will disappear

3) With the keyboard resigned, the x remains in the `UISearchBar`

4) Tap the x in the `UISearchBar` and the text in the `SearchBar` disappears and the view refreshes

5) At this point, the navigation bar button should be enabled again, but it's not.

Code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    self.timelineSearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    if ([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        [self.timelineSearchBar performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder)
                    withObject:nil
                  afterDelay:0];
    }
```

I know that the code above is meant to dismiss the keyboard when the x is pressed which is fine.

In my case, the keyboard is already resigned, so I want the tapping of the x to just re-enable the navigation bar item.

```
    self.addButton.enabled = YES;
```

in that if statement above doesn't do anything at all and the navigation bar item is still disabled.

I've even tried in that if statement :

```
[self.timelineSearchBar performSelector:@selector(enableAdd)
                    withObject:nil
                  afterDelay:0];

- (void)enableAdd
{
    self.addButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

but that crashes saying searchBar does not respond to that enableAdd selector.

I've done a breakpoint and see that the if statement above does evaluate to true when I tap the x and it goes into the statement, it "runs" the code to enable the button, but it never happens.

Also my end editing method is:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    self.addButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

UPDATE: I've tried the link here http://engineeringtheworld.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/detecting-when-clear-is-clicked-in-uisearchbar-x-button/ with no success - the textField's shouldClear method doesn't get called. I'm using iOS 7 so perhaps there's another way to embed the views with textFields? This is very possibly the right approach, but it's not working with my code because the for statement in that sample never gets evaluated as true (I put in an NSLog).

UPDATE 2: From if the if statement above, I called the searchBarCancelButton method and I had extreme loops being caused, so that of course wasn't the right approach:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(searchBarCancelButtonClicked:) withObject:self.timelineSearchBar afterDelay: 0];
```

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated. I know I'm missing a key step but I just can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Where are you setting `addButton.enabled = NO` ?

Comment: Hi Michael, in the searchBarShouldBeginEditing and in the     searchBarSearchButtonClicked with an if ([self.timelineSearchBar.text length] > 0) statement , the else enables the button again in this delegate method. No where else is it being set to NO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when tapping the X button, `searchBar:textDidChange:` is called *before* `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:`

i.e. here is the call flow: `searchBar:textDidChange:` -> `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:` -> `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:` -> `searchBarTextDidEndEditing:`

`textDidChange` is setting enabled to YES, but then `shouldBeginEditing` is disabling it again. This works perfectly for me:

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    self.addButton.enabled = NO;
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    if(searchBar.text.length == 0){
        self.addButton.enabled = YES;
    }
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if ([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        [searchBar performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    }
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    self.addButton.enabled = [searchBar.text length] == 0;
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @michaels - I really appreciate your thoughts and work with this. I have answered the question as well for clarity with what I did to get this working but I never would have got there without your input and I almost got your code working; just had to tweak it a bit. Thanks again for your help and would be really interested to getting your thoughts with the approach I had to use to get it working

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if([searchText length] == 0 && searchBar.text.length == 0)
    {
        self.addButton.enabled = YES;
        [searchBar performSelector: @selector(resignFirstResponder)
                    withObject: nil
                    afterDelay: 0.1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Goutham - that's helpful but unfortunately it's the same result. What I'm seeing is, with the keyboard up (isFirstResponder), if I tap the cancel button, then the keyboard resigns AND the Nav Bar Button (addButton) becomes enabled. However, with the keyboard already resignFirstResponder, the x in the UISearchBar does not enable the nav bar button item. I wonder if this is a bug in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating an answer here for clarity, but the answer by Michaels helped massively and is the accepted approach here, although I got my code working.

I did a lot of digging around with `NSLogs` and interestingly, I discovered that the `shouldBeginEditing` appeared before the `textDidChange` (in the order of the NSLogs).

However, I also noticed that in the steps in my original question, with the keyboard dismissed and the UISearchBar containing text and the x visible, if I tapped x, the keyboard didn't appear, but it called `shoudlBeginEditing` again.

This was the method that was causing the addButton to continue to be greyed out because that method set that button to be disabled.

So I adjusted the code:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)bar
{
    NSLog(@"Should begin");
    if ([self.timelineSearchBar.text length] > 0)
    {
        self.addButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.addButton.enabled = YES;
    }
    self.timelineSearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    BOOL boolToReturn = self.shouldBeginEditing;
    self.shouldBeginEditing = YES;
    return boolToReturn;
}
```

I put the if condition in there so that the code reacted appropriately if I went back to the searchBar after cancelling with the x.

This way, the add button does not disable as soon as I click on the `UISearchBar` (which brings up the keyboard). However, in the `textDidChange` (which is what I saw gets called from the very first letter being typed), I put the following condition too:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    NSLog(@"Text did change");
    self.timelineSearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    if ([self.timelineSearchBar.text length] > 0)
    {
        self.addButton.enabled = NO;
    }
...
}
```

This way, the `UISearchBar` would only display the add button when I start typing in a letter. This worked for me because if the user tapped on the `UISearchBar` and did not type anything in, in the `prepareForSegue` that went to the view that the Add Entry was calling, I checked if the searchBar `isFirstResponder` and if so, I `resignFirstResponder`.

With this in mind, I'm not sure if this is the Apple way of doing things, but it's clean. I'll know soon enough if my app gets rejected because of this, but thanks so much for your help Michaels; you really pointed me in the right direction for an issue that took up my entire afternoon!

Comment: Glad to see you got it working! I very much doubt you'll get your app rejected because of this since you are not using any private APIs or doing anything dangerous (in my opinion). I'm surprised you saw that `shouldBeginEditing` is called before `textDidChange` - I had the opposite result on my side, but hey, if it works it works!

Comment: Absolutely! Confusing, but it works and I'm happy :) Thanks Michaels again - really appreciate it!